# awk and newline after final column

Tags: bash, awk

I have an input file of which a sample is:

```
8101010447 25.09 40n50.76  15e06.74   4.96  999  -----  0.2388 314  6.90 99.00  60   6 81EV00001
8101010929 23.85 42n47.96  12e47.90   8.90  3.0  MCSTI  0.0917 123  0.60  2.80  47  16 81EV00002
8101011100 14.41 40n52.23  15e20.57   7.34  999  -----  0.7021 123  0.40  1.30  67  11 81EV00003
```

and I need to get the last and fourth columns. I am using awk to get the columns correctly but the last column has a newline character at the end so the columns are outputted on separate lines.

My code is the following:

```
awk -F' ' '{print $14, $4}' catalog.txt >> bbb.txt
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

The final output should look like:

```
81EV00001 15e06.74
81EV00002 12e47.99
81EV00003 15e20.57
```

Comment: Probably `awk '{print $NF, $4}' file` suffices, since `-F' '` is the default and `$NF` matches the last field. However, it is not clear how the output should look like. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: It should be 81EV00001 15e06.74 for the first line

Comment: Please provide the output you get, preferably with `cat -vET`.

Comment: Your existing output has a spurious newline, or a spurious carriage return? (The latter seems far more likely). And if it's a CR... well, could you just strip them all? Do you want your output to have CRLFs, as your input does, or does unix-style LF-only work?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The last column of a file usually has a newline after it (unless you end each line with spaces). But `awk` doesn't include the newline in the `$14` value.

Comment: Is my comment invisible? :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath not sure what you are asking

Comment: @Barmar it seems it is getting the newline as well

Comment: See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `CR` characters before printing:

```
awk '{ sub("\r", "", $14); print $14, $4; }' catalog.txt >> bbb.txt
```

The `sub()` function replaces one string with another string; in this case, I replace the `\r` character in column 14 with an empty string.

Comment: I've added an explanation, although it seems like it should be obvious, assuming you know what the `sub()` function does.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this on a DOS file with \r\n at the end of the row.  Therefore the final column had a \r tacked onto it because the default RS in awk/gawk is \n.

The solution is simple.  Make the RS \r\n i.e.

```
RS="\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try these approaches, in order to get the fields (awk) and remove the unwanted symbols (tr):

Removing CR:

```
awk -F' ' '{print $14, $4}' catalog.txt | tr -d '\r' > bbb.txt
```

Removing LF:

```
awk -F' ' '{print $14, $4}' catalog.txt | tr -d '\n' > bbb.txt
```

Removing both CR and LF:

```
awk -F' ' '{print $14, $4}' catalog.txt | tr -d "\r\n" > bbb.txt
```

Comment: Why are you using a temp file instead of piping the output through `tr`?

Comment: Indeed, piping is a way more straightforward approach. Edited.