# can't print anything after last field using awk

Tags: awk

I'm having trouble doing something very simple with awk.  I'd like to print the last field, followed by another field.

Input file looks like this:

```
03 Oct 22,  Southern ,Mad,WIN,Gro,,33.10
03 Oct 22,  Mpd ,Mad,WIN,Auto,-208.56,
23 Sep 22,  Thank  ,n/a,WIN,,-97.93,
```

This way round works fine:

```
$ awk -F',' '{print "first " $6 " and then " $7}' input.csv
first  and then 33.10
first -208.56 and then
first -97.93 and then
```

But when I swap the fields over I get the strangest result:

```
$ awk -F',' '{print "first " $7 " and then " $6}' input.csv
and then 0
and then -208.56
and then -97.93
```

I must be missing something really simple.  What on earth is going on?

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
```

Comment: Please show output of this command: `file input.csv`

Comment: your input file contains windows/dos line endings (`\r\n`) so after printing `$7` you have a `\r` which moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line before printing `and then $6`; the easy solution is to remove the `\r` characters (eg, `dos2unix input.csv` - only has to be run once as this updates the file), or modify your code to remove the `\r` (eg, `{ gsub(/\r/,""); print ...}`)

Comment: See: [awk and newline after final column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34162239/3776858)

Comment: fwiw, something like `head -3 input.csv | od -c` should show the sequence `\r \n` at the end of each line

Answer (score 0):

Only suggestion I have is to update awk.  It works perfectly fine on my MacBook - with this version:

awk --version
GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)

Comment: this has nothing to do with awk version, it's an input file issue.